# How does rollback changeset work?

Tags: rollback, changeset, tfvc

Let us say we are using TFVC and we have just one file under source control.

After changeset 1, it looks like:

> ```
> 1111
> ```

After changeset 2, it becomes:

> ```
> 12121212
> ```

After changeset 3, it becomes:

> ```
> 123123123123
> ```

Now if I roll back changeset 2, what will this file become and why? I feel that understanding this is fundamental to understanding changesets, rollbacks and version control.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Have you tried? I suspect it will cause a merge conflict and require you to manually resolve it.